# Saving canvas draw in bitmap showing white screen

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to save canvas draw into bitmap using this code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        myBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap((int)this.getWidth(), (int)this.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);// bitmap created
        canvas=new Canvas(myBitmap);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    }
```

For paint code :

```
public TouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }
```

According to the concept it should draw lines on touching screen but when I run the app code only white screen shows and I am not able to draw anything!

Note:

The app runs correctly if I remove:

```
myBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap((int)this.getWidth(), (int)this.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);// bitmap created
    canvas=new Canvas(myBitmap);
```

But I want to save my canvas in a bitmap for future processing .

How to save canvas in bitmap correctly ? What changes should I bring ?

Comment: you are not using the original `canvas` inside `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`

Comment: How to use it ?

Comment: call some `draw*` method on it?

Comment: Any small example please ?

Comment: Is `canvas.drawPath()` is not a method ?

Comment: See above I have called it already !

Comment: it is but `canvas` is not the original `canvas` any more, since you are calling `canvas=new Canvas(myBitmap);`

Comment: Then how to make it **original** I don't understand what do you mean by **original**

Comment: **original** means the `Canvas` that is passed to `onDraw` method

Comment: Do you want me to remove `canvas=new canvas(myBitmap)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123053/discussion-between-utkarsh-dubey-and-pskink).